# sending request with curl returns that method does not exist

Tags: json-rpc

I try to make call with curl

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":67}' http://localhost:8545`

and it returns this:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"the method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available"}}`

Why is it this way? Did I miss something in request?

Comment: Are you making a call to a geth instance? or some other client?

Comment: @Ismael: Can you please review [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83103/16043)?

Comment: @Ismael , what do you mean by that? I'm sending curl request to ip:port where my eth is setup.

Comment: @Mortelity From the error message the server listening for json-rpc requests doesn't understand `eth_acctounts`. If the server you are using is geth then you haven't enabled `eth` api. You have to search for the server if they have a flag to turn on/off the api they provide.

Comment: @Ismael, I have these enabled: ```--rpcapi 'eth,personal,admin,debug,net,rpc,txpool,db,web3'```

Comment: @Mortelity What version of geth are you using?

Comment: @Ismael, which method do I need to use to check that?

Comment: @Mortelity Running `geth version` should output version numbers.

Comment: @Ismael , Version: 1.9.13-stable