# can anyone explain why call, delegateCall, staticCall functions in solidity are called low level functions?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix, solidity-0.6.x

As i have read at many resources, that these functions are `low level functions`. I want to know, should i use these methods to interact with already deployed contracts or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They allow you to perform dynamic invocation (instead of static invocation) of a contract function.

This is similar to *reflection* in Java, where you execute a function using the function name string.

It is also similar to how you can call a function in interpreted languages like Python or Javascript.

For example:

```
def func(x):
   return x * 2
y = eval("func")(3)
print(y)
```

Or:

```
function func(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
const y = eval("func")(3);
console.log(y);
```

In a strong-typed language like Solidity, it means that the function which will be executed during runtime is not determined by the compiler, i.e., it is not hard-coded in the bytecode that the compiler generates.

These low level functions are useful in several different scenarios, here are some of them:

- You're not sure about the type(s) of the return value(s)
- You want to handle a failure without reverting