# what's the difference between call and just using function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

Let's say I have a contract called `contractA`.

It has the function:

```
function bla(address test) {
    // way 1. test.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("first4bytes", arg1, arg2))
    // way 2. testAddrInterface(test).functName()
}
```

As you can see, in the way 2 example, I just use the interface so that I can call `functName` on it directly instead of using way 1.

I've seen lots of places that people use way 1. Why ? what's wrong with Way 2? if you tell me way 2 contains more code and is more gas costly, I will ask: are the interfaces still included in the final code and is this the only reason why Way 1 is better ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can anyone explain why call, delegateCall, staticCall functions in solidity are called low level functions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/can-anyone-explain-why-call-delegatecall-staticcall-functions-in-solidity-are)

Comment: The title of that other question is not the same as yours, but I believe that it essentially refers to the same issues. In either case, you can read my answer there, which lists a couple of reason for using `call`.

Comment: I understand the difference if using delegatecall. but if using call, the function that it calls is known at run-time and even at compile time. don't you think ?

Comment: No, you are passing the function prototype (name and input argument types) as string. You can even let an external user (for example) pass it as input to a function in your contract. So no, it is definitely does not correspond with "known during compile time".

Comment: In strongly-typed languages, any function which is known during compilation time is immediately replaced by the compiler with a jump to the address of the function in the code (and I guess that something similar to that happens in solidity). When you `call` a function by its string prototype, the actual decision of "where to jump" occurs only during runtime.

Comment: Ah, Got it. What about return values ? one way or another, I still have to know the return values.

Comment: No you don't. The function signature consists of only its name and the types of input arguments. That is why using `call` allows you to actually execute a function without knowing its return-value type (as you can read at the bottom of the answer to the question that I linked above).

Comment: Yes, but you say that it's useful when `You're not sure about the type(s) of the return value(s)`. How will this help me ? even if i use `call` , I still need to know what the return values are

Comment: Very useful. Consider for example, that I have a Main contract which interacts with a bunch of contracts of the same type. Each one of them has some `function func(uint x) returns (uint)`. At some later point, I decide to extend it to  `returns (uint, uint)`. I cannot upgrade the older contracts which are already deployed, but I still wanna add instances of the new version. Now my Main contract needs to handle both function types. They have the exact prototype - `"func(uint)"`, but I cannot use an interface, because I do not know which version exists in each contract. Got it?

Comment: You are correct that something in the workflow needs to know what type to expect from the called function. But by accepting the raw bytes, you have more flexibility. As @goodvibration describes.

You could forward or return the raw bytes to a contract that is coded for explicit types. Or try to interpret the raw bytes yourself. Depending on the tuple structure, you can still extract the result using a hard coded type. Which is what goodvibration describes.

Comment: yes, i understand that in these cases, interfaces won't be a solution. but in that case of using `call`, then I in advance have to know how much bytes to take as returned value so that i know how many parameters the call returns and which parameter is which.  Does this make sense ?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: while we are here, can you guys explain the second use case quickly ? `You want to handle a failure without reverting` ?

Comment: So, based on your question, where it seems your intent is to understand if there's a difference in how using the interfaces actually calls the other contract, there is none.

The interface just tells the compiler to include all the encoding and decoding code for you, but uses the same low level call operation to execute the function.

Comment: The default error handling you get from using interfaces will revert the transaction if you get a failure. This could be trying to call a function on a contract that doesn't exist, and whose fallback function doesn't handle the call. This would typically be when you expect to get a meangingful response, like an address, but just get a true.

I would recommend writing some test code to experiment. It will help you understand first hand what is going on. You can use a gas reporter plugin to monitor the effects.

Answer (score 2):

The more important difference is that if `funcName` reverts then for case 2 `bla` will also revert.

For case 2 calls returns a boolean indicating if the call has failed, and have the posibility to ignore the failure.

Using raw call is low level and discouraged because it is easy to make mistakes. Since solc 0.6 you can use [`try/catch`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/control-structures.html#try-catch)

```
    try myContract.funcName(param1, param2, ..) returns (uint retValue) {
        /* Do something with retValue */
    } catch Error(string memory err) {
        /* Do something with the error message and revert */
    }
```

Another place where case 1 is the only option is when making arbitrary calls since at compile time you don't know the function name nor the parameters, for example proxy contracts, multisig wallets, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Effectively, there is no difference.

Using an interface provides compile time safety checks on arguments used. And simplifies the usage of return values the same way.

This is a quick, simple example, but basically these code lines are equivalent.

```
<Type> returnTuple = address.call( <payload as byyes> );

<Type> returnTuple = address.call( abi.encodeWithSelector( <Function Selector>, <Arguments . . .>);

<Type> returnTuple = address.call( abi.encodeWithSignature( <Function Selector string>, <Arguments . . .>);

<Type> returnTuple = address.f( <arguments> );
```

All would revert if the return tuple doesn't fit. When using call, you would normally accept the raw bytes. And then work with it from there. Such as returning, forwarding, or parseing.

Comment: That's not correct. There are several notable differences, see [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83103/16043).

Comment: Not in this example. Since the selector is hard coded, this code doesn't allow for dynamic execution.

Comment: And the answer you cite is a longer way of saying compile time type safety checks.

So in the context of the question, which is concerning the technical difference in executing the function call to another contract, there is no difference. The function call is executed the same way. Both simply use the low level call( bytes payload ); The interface just layers the payload encoding providing type safety checks during compile time.

Comment: Here is one difference: if the 2nd option reverts for an internal implementation reason (i.e., not because the function doesn't exist), then the 1st option will not revert. In other words, the 1st option allows you to handle failures "your way" (kinda like try/catch in other languages). So stating 'no differences', IMO is wrong.

Comment: In addition, in the 1st option, the compiler generates code which expects `(bool, bytes memory)` to return. In the 2nd option, the compiler generates code which expects whatever is defined in the interface to return. So by no means are these two options equivalent in terms of compilation **or** runtime.

Comment: Ok, then write a more complete answer. or edit mine. I still classify all that as compile time type safety checks. Using the function alerts you that the target contract is not of the appropriate type for the call you're making. Enforcing that in runtime. Effectively acting as a default exception handler during runtime by enforcing the compile time type safety check.

Thus, the execution is still the same. Thus, no difference in the context of the question, which is about the difference in execution. They're executed the same way.

Comment: If one reverts and the other one doesn't, then they're obviously **not** executed the same way.

Comment: You mean both execute with call but one automatically includes code to check the result? 

Hmm, so both *execute* using call, but one includes post-processing during compile time to add type safety checks in the byte code. Which means there's no difference in how the external function is *executed*, but one includes post-processing *after* the execution.

Try using a sequence diagram to understand what is actually happening at the low level OP is asking about.

Comment: No, I mean exactly as shown in the question - 1st option is executed via `call` and 2nd option is executed via the interface. The 2nd option may revert because of some internal issue, for example - a false `require` statement. The same issue will not cause the 1st option to revert, just to return `false` in the first (out of two) returned values. Hence - these two options are **not executed the same way** as you insist.

Comment: Moreover, as I've already mentioned, **outside** the function (i.e., back in the contract of this user), there are two different "setups" - one expects a return of `(bool, bytes memory)`, while the other expects a return of whatever is defined in the interface. So again, it's a whole different execution code (and behavior) in each case.

Comment: @goodvibration good point. I was focused on the execution of the called function, not on the result. but you raise a good point. When using call, you have to account for the implications of receiving a false.

But, I still don't consider the difference in the resulting bytecode as significant. Depending on the compiler and language, using additive assignment results in different assembly then explicitly declaring the variables.

a = a + b
versus
a += b

Results in the same value, but can use different operations. But the relevance is subjective.